# Pass value from Previous page to first page using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have two VF page and two apex class,i want to pass value from VF page 2 (textbox1) to Vf page 1(account lookup textbox1) using javascript.i searched lot links but i can't achieve this.Please help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On page 1

```
baseURL = "/apex/page2";
openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
```

On page 2

```
<apex:outputLink value="javascript:top.window.opener. js function name  ('{!a.Name}');self.close();" >{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. On Page 2 I am clicking on the Save button instead of "outputLink".